# Pieshaped Buttons in Windows forms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, button

Im trying to make some custombuttons for windows forms in c#, I already have a pieshaped button this is the sourcecode

```
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Drawing;

    namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
    {
        public class RoundButton : Button
        {
           protected override void OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
            {
                GraphicsPath grPath = new GraphicsPath();
                grPath.AddPie(new Rectangle(10, 10, 500, 500), 180, 18);
                this.Region = new System.Drawing.Region(grPath);
                base.OnPaint(e);
            }
        }

    }
```

The Problem is that the Position and Size are fix but i want them to be variable, it would be great if someone could help me.

Comment: surely its just a case of making the dimensions into properties on the RoundButton class so you can set them to something else?

Comment: yeah but i dont know how to do it i want it to be like
PSEUDOCODE
grPath.AddPie(New Rectangle(PositionX, PositionY,             SizeX, SizeY), StartingAngle, Size) and it should be changeable via Mousedrag

Comment: OnPaint() should **never** contain code that causes another paint to be generated.  You should set the Region property in the constructor.  Or in OnResize().  Which of course gives you a good way to figure out what size the pie should be, simply use new Rectangle(Point.Empty, this.Size).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a new Rectangle object, how about using "e.ClipRectangle"? I tried it out at my end it worked (sort of) but not very sure if this is what you want.

Also the button was disappearing when the mouse entered/leaved the button so I had to override the said events. You need to handle that as well.

The following is the code.

```
public class RoundButton : Button
{
    protected override void OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        var rect = e.ClipRectangle;

        System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath grPath = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
        //grPath.AddPie(new Rectangle(1, 1, 10, 10), 180, 18);
        grPath.AddPie(rect, 0, 360);

        this.Region = new System.Drawing.Region(grPath);
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        //Need to handle this more elegantly
        //base.OnMouseEnter(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        //Need to handle this more elegantly
        //base.OnMouseLeave(e);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.